# Does Dr. Chase really come up with more correct diagnoses than anyone else?

Tags: plot-explanation, house

I recently came across this bit of trivia for *House MD* on IMDb , which says that:

> Though other characters occasionally insinuate that Dr Chase is a bit dim, he actually comes up with more correct diagnoses than any other supporting character over the course of the series.

Which leads me to my question, is there any proof to this bit of trivia or is it pure user-contributed conjecture?

Since I wasn't able to find any documented proof of the number of correct diagnoses that any cast member on *House MD* has given throughout the show's eight seasons.

Comment: Trivia can be added by any user on IMDB and has zero verification. A good chunk of it is really interesting, informative and can be googled and verified. But there's also a big chunk of it that is pure conjecture, with no verifiable sources.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I thought, since I myself couldn't find any proof to many of the trivia mentioned there which is why most of them seemed
 to be pure conjecture.

Comment: So to check, what *is* your question here. Because it doesn't really fit asking about IMDB, because we *know* it's trivia. But you could remove that second paragraph, and just ask about if Chase has made the most correct diagnoses in the series - that would be very much on-topic.

Comment: @AndrewMartin : Sure, my question was in fact about the verifiability of this particular bit of trivia, the bit about IMDb was just something I wanted to find out in general, I've changed my question.

Comment: I like the idea of this question, but I'm stuck on how to answer it. Take the pilot episode. The patient had *Neurocysticercosis*.House suggested it, but to confirm it she needed treatment. She refused. Chase suggested an x-ray, which she assented to, and the illness was apparent. So who gets the diagnosis credit? Chase actually confirmed it, but House was the one who spotted it?

Comment: Well, I guess according to me, the credit should go to the cast member who mentioned the actual disease that turned out to be the final diagnosis, in the case of the pilot, I guess it should go to House, shouldn't it ? In essence, Chase just helped confirm the diagnosis, but didn't come up with it.

Comment: I suppose so. I know that in many episodes the solution is suggested at the very start as a throwout, then ruled out... then it's later realised they made an incorrect assumption and the initial suggestion *was* correct. But the person who made the initial suggestion doesn't know that - House usually does! So it's a minefield identifying responsibility :)

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I guess in the end you have to give it to the guy who mentioned it first, even though it was an incorrect assumption then, he threw it out there nonetheless.

Comment: Is it lupus? or ALS?

Comment: Okay. This might take a while...

Comment: Luckily, chase is only part of the scoobies for 5 seasons, not 8, so that cuts it down a bit.

Comment: @cde: But to know if he's got the most, you'd have to do all eight seasons...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Yes, I believe Chase comes up with more correct diagnoses than any other supporting character**.

Firstly, this is obviously a *very* difficult question to answer. As discussed in the comments, how do we *know* who made a diagnosis? For example:

- Sometimes the entire team take part in an exploratory procedure where something is discovered. Who gets credit? The first person to call the name of the disease out? Or the person who actually finds it?
- Often ideas are brainstormed at the start of an episode. These ideas may cover anywhere from two - twenty possible illnesses. If one of those turns out to be correct, do we give credit to whoever first threw it out, or whoever actually demonstrated the victim suffered from it?
- Illnesses can be identified at a high level, but not understood at a low level. For example, it might be suggested a patient has cancer. Is that enough to claim the diagnosis? Do they need to have pinpointed where and how?
- Sometimes a diagnosis is identified, but it's not understood. Later, it is discovered a much more minor illness caused the onset of the first illness. So the first illness is more serious, but the second was the focus of the episode - so who gets credit here. The diagnoser of the serious illness, or of the secondary, less serious (and often psychological) illness?

  - Some episodes all the solutions are written up at the start on a whiteboard, and crossed off one by one. No one speaks, but someone writes them all (as the possible solutions are obvious to everyone). Who gets credit here? The person doing the writing? Or the team?

These are just some of the many, many difficulties inherent in trying to understand who is the most successful diagnoser in the team.

Despite this, I've tried to do this and my results suggest Chase is indeed the second most successful member of the team, behind House.

**Methodology**

There are eight seasons worth of content. That is obviously *a lot*. On top of that, it would be incredibly time consuming to go through each individual episode to try and pinpoint this information. Doing so would make this answer perfect, but I doubt anyone has time to do this, unless they're going on a House binge.

Instead, I chose to use the [House Wiki](http://house.wikia.com/wiki/House_Wiki). It has a very handy [list of medical diagnoses](http://house.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_medical_diagnoses) which details what every patient, in every episode, what suffering from.

I then opened up every single episode description and read through to understand who the first person to claim the illness in the episode was:

- In a very few episodes it's unclear, so I labelled the diagnoser as "Team".
- In most, it's a clear win for House.
- In quite a few others, one of the doctors claims it early and their suspicions are confirmed later. In these cases I gave them credit, as they had initially suggested it.
- Often they suggested a general disease (e.g. cancer, or meningitis) and the answer was a subset of these. In these cases, I gave credit to the person who came up with the subset (usually House).

To understand who was most successful, I compiled a spreadsheet ([a copy of which I've hosted on Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OcKgnpSSWp1qAeejTm-f9bG34DlSiubUaiAnH6cy8Og/edit?usp=sharing)). This cross references every season/episode/patient/disease with their diagnoser.

**Results**:

This graphs shows the Total # of Diagnoses made by every character across the entire eight seasons:

<sub>(*Note: Please open to view it in full size*)</sub>

[image]

As can be seen, the results (in order) are:

1. **House**: 117
2. **Chase**: 20
3. **Team** *(i.e. more than one person appeared to come up with the diagnosis at the same time)*: 13
4. **Foreman**: 9
5. **Hadley** ("13"): 9
6. **Cameron**: 6
7. **Taub**: 5
8. **Wilson**: 2
9. **Adams**: 2
10. **Kutner**: 2
11. **Park**: 1
12. **Volakis**: 1
13. **Cuddy**: 1
14. **Masters**: 1

So this would indeed suggest that Chase, by a comfortable margin, is the second best diagnoser after House.

If interested, we can look at the same results, broken down season by season:

<sub>(*Note: Please open to view it in full size*)</sub>

[image]

House is top every season, but the second best diagnoser each season is as follows:

1. Season 1: Team: 4
2. Season 2: Tie - Chase: 3 / Team: 3
3. Season 3: Chase: 5
4. Season 4: Tie - Hadley: 2 / Kutner: 2
5. Season 5: Tie - Cameron: 2 / Hadley: 2
6. Season 6: Foreman: 3
7. Season 7: Team: 4
8. Season 8: Chase: 4

Of course, it's important to note that simply having the most diagnoses doesn't make him the best doctor. Cameron has just a single diagnosis in Season 1. Foreman has none. But they were instrumental that season, helping House out, performing valuable work (and breaking and entering) and were involved in every episode. It just *appears* as if they haven't done as much, as the final diagnosis didn't originate with them.

**Accuracy**

I will quickly repeat that this has come from a Wikipedia page and a basic study of data generated within that Wikipedia page. I'm sure it's not 100% accurate and I'm sure there will be at least a few mistakes.

However, it seems a good indicator and given Chase's clear margin of second place, I'd be confident saying your initial question was correct.

**Conclusion**:

With all the results in, and even accounting for the fact some of this information may be incorrect, it seems *very likely* Chase does in fact come up with the correct diagnosis more than any other *supporting character* (with House obviously dominating the diagnosis table).

**Edit**:

@Anthony Grist posted the following comment below:

> It might be interesting to see it as a percentage of episodes they
>   appear in as part of House's team, since I have a feeling Chase also
>   had the most opportunities to make the correct diagnosis. In terms of
>   raw numbers he might come second, but his actual success rate could be
>   a lot worse than other team members who appeared in fewer seasons.

This was a really interesting idea, so I decided to plot this as well.

I used IMDB for a [full list of cast credits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0412142/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt) for the show. This shows the following:

- House: 176 episodes
- "Team": 176 episodes
- Foreman: 174 episodes
- Wilson: 174 episodes
- Chase: 171 episodes
- Cuddy: 153 episodes
- Cameron: 130 episodes
- Taub: 96 episodes
- Hadley: 81 episodes
- Kutner: 37 episodes
- Adams: 21 episodes
- Park: 21 episodes
- Volakis: 18 episodes
- Masters: 15 episodes

I then updated the spreadsheet [changes are on Google Spreadsheet as well](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OcKgnpSSWp1qAeejTm-f9bG34DlSiubUaiAnH6cy8Og/edit?usp=sharing) with this information, cross referenced it with the number of diagnoses made per character and calculated the character's overall diagnosis success rate. This reveals the following:

[image]

So *House* leads the way, with the correct diagnosis in **66.48%** of all his episodes.

*Chase* is *still* in second plac,e but it's very, very close. He made the correct diagnosis in **11.70%** of his episodes, whilst *Hadley* is in third place, with the correct diagnosis in **11.11%** of her episodes.

The following graph shows the same information, but includes the number of episodes each character starred in, with a trendline indicating success rate. Note the big drop off after *House*, and how close *Chase* and *Hadley* are.

[image]

Comment: It would be interesting to see a comparison between how many times someone guesses what the diagnosis is and how often they are correct... It's totally possible that Chase simply guesses more often than the others... it would be interesting to see who is more often correct when they do guess.

Comment: I want to bounty this, but I can't yet.

Comment: @cde: Thank you so much, that's very kind of you :)

Comment: @Catija: I did notice that *a lot* of the episodes I looked through where he "won" the diagnosis, he had thrown it out as a suggestion at the start but it had been ruled out, only for them to discover some lie, or discrepancy later and realise it was true. More than half of his "wins" came that way, without a eureka breakthrough moment, but as casual suggestions.

Comment: It might be interesting to see it as a percentage of episodes they appear in as part of House's team, since I have a feeling Chase also had the most opportunities to make the correct diagnosis. In terms of raw numbers he might come second, but his actual success rate could be a lot worse than other team members who appeared in fewer seasons.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist; Done. Chase still wins second, but only by a hare over Hadley.

Comment: Then again, how many eps was Chase *in* but not part of the differential? That would skew the numbers back the other way, too. For quite a while, he wasn't part of the team, but still part of the supporting cast. If he was only in one scene and never gave any diagnoses, does that really count?

Comment: @Roger: Another fair point :)

Comment: I look at your data and decide there is some modification necessary. Chase spend entire season 4 and 5 outside of diagnostic team. There are a total of 47 episodes where he is not part of diagnostic teams. Therefore his actual tally on diagnostic team is 171 minus 47; 124. Thus his actual percentage is 16.13%

Comment: The above is somewhat in correct and you really dont need the graphs ROFLLLLLL. Chase is correct 80% of the time, above house. He is correct with iNITIAL diagnoses more then ANYONE; There is a reason the show ends with him on the door.

Comment: The Google Docs link sadly appears to be broken, can you fix it? (In case OP doesn't respond, is there a chance anyone from this comment thread saved the spreadsheet and can reupload it?)